# Reducing redundancy in Python doc-strings while using pylint docparams

Tags: python, pylint, docstring

I'm writing some Python code that's being checked with pylint with the [docparams](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/1.9/technical_reference/extensions.html?highlight=docparams) extension. This requires documenting function parameters in their docstrings. I have a tendency to try to [decompose functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_decomposition) as much as possible and end up with lots of [functions that call other functions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141251/functions-that-only-call-other-functions-is-this-a-good-practice) - often sharing many of the same parameters. This can lead to lots of redundant (copy-pasted) documentation in the docstrings. Is there a recommended way of dealing with this type of situation?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to run into this same problem later while working on a Pyramid app, so I googled and found [docrep](http://docrep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  I think it'll satisfy both of our needs.

Comment: The module you suggested ([docrep](http://docrep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) looks cool, but the docs say it only works with numpy-style docstrings. I actually have to stick to google-style docstrings, so I don't think I'll be able to use it on this project.